# Why is ItemsControl in the following WPF XAML not showing anything?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, itemscontrol

When I run the app, I expect to see 5 buttons (see ItemsControl\DataTemplate\Button in my XAML below) each with a content like "55/42" denoting max ad min temperature. However, the window is blank. I know this has to do with ItemsControl because I can display the data without using the ItemsControl. Can someone catch my mistake?

```
<Window x:Class="Embed_WeatherSummaryAsItemsControl_ToMain.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=InputCity}"
    Title="Weather App" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox x:Name="InputCity" Grid.Row="0" Width="200" Text="{Binding CityAndOptionalCountry}"></TextBox>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Width="50" Content="Go" Margin="260,0,0,0" Command="{Binding GetWeatherReportCommand}"></Button>
    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding WeatherForecastSummaryCollection}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="{Binding Path=MaxMinTemperature}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>          
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

As shown below, "WeatherForecastSummaryCollection" is a collection property on ViewModel class and "MaxMinTemperature" is a property of item in collection.

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    ....

    private List<WeatherForecastSummary> mWeatherForecastSummaryCollection;
    public List<WeatherForecastSummary> WeatherForecastSummaryCollection
    {
        get { return mWeatherForecastSummaryCollection; }
        set
        {
            mWeatherForecastSummaryCollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("WeatherForecastSummaryCollection");
        }
    }
    .....
}

public class WeatherForecastSummary
{
    public string MaxMinTemperature { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: How do you populate the collection and bind the control to it?

Comment: Can you show the code where you actually instantiate the collection and add the 5 items to it?

Comment: I guess you first asign an empty list to `WeatherForecastSummaryCollection` and then add the 5 items (which is the standard way). But the List does not send notification about content changes. Change the type `List<WeatherForecastSummary>` to `ObservableCollection<WeatherForecastSummary>` will help.

Comment: Yes that was it - I forgot to make the list observable. Thanks gomi42!!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing the DataContext here.
Even if you are using the codebehind of the View, you need to write

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

or if you are using someother class as viewmodel you might want to point the datacontext to that class. Just replace "this" in the above code with your viewmodels object.
In this case it would be ,

```
this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
```

Comment: App xaml code-behind does have that data context set. I add a method to override OnStartup of App which is where I instantiate MainWindow and MainWindowVM, set MainWindow's DataContext to MainWindowVM and finally do MainWindow.Show(). I'm only having a problem with ItemsControl. I can bind to another single button control without any problem so I know DataContext is not the problem unless I need to set DataContext again separately for ItemsControl.

Comment: I am unsure why you are doing that ??. Would be able to just move that bit of code as i have shown above into the constructor of the Page which you want to bind to your MainWindowViewModel.

Comment: Aditya, no View or Page or Window code-behinds are to modified using the MVVM design pattern. Your advice would not solve the problem because the culprit was the "observable" collection as gomi42 pointed out above! The code is working now.